# Django FilteredSelectMultiple with a massive amount of data

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-widget

I have the following models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ground'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)


class Program(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ground'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

And the following admin:

```
class ProgramAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {
            'widget': admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
                Student._meta.verbose_name_plural, False)
        }
    }

admin.site.register(Program, ProgramAdmin)
```

As you can see I use django's FilteredSelectMultiple to display a nice select field for the Program admin where I can select multiple students at once.

**Problem**
I have over 2500 students in the database. The browser has problems with rendering all students into the select field. Is there a way to overcome this problem. Like doing stuff with javascript

Answer (score 1):

It's not a browser problem. Django is fetching a list of data of *all* the students on every single load. If you keep it that way, it will be slow and slower. You can check out [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently writing my own autocomplete widget... Stay tuned!